# How to connect DRV-8835 to arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, motor

I try to connect arduino with motor using DRV-8835. The problem I have - simply nothing happens. I used tutorial from http://www.instructables.com/id/The-SnapMobile-Start-Your-Physical-Computing-Engin/step6/Building-the-Prototype-Wiring-Up-the-Arduino-the-D/

Code for arduino:

```
void setup() {
    pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
  analogWrite(5, 255);
}
```

Maybe someone has scheme how to connect wires to motor. Now I'm not sure if I made a mistake or motor driver is broken.

[image]

Comment: You might try wiring the enable and direction pins active (high?) to skip the arduino.  But check the motor wiring, too.  Do the motors spin when directly connected to your motor power supply without the PCB?  (The motor supply voltage is appropriate for the motors, right?  And you aren't running them off the Arduino or USB power?  And these are DC motors, not steppers or something more exotic?)

Comment: I use http://www.dagurobot.com/goods.php?id=86 . In fact I didn't try to connect battery(4x 1.5V) to motor. I'm newbie and little afraid of destroy motor

Comment: Ok. I tried without arduino and motor driver and motor works so it's not motor fault

Comment: Do you have any LEDs and resistors you could use to check the Arduino outputs in place of the motor driver?  Or you could use a voltmeter to measure them.

Comment: Yes. I checked it and there is no output - at least using LED and resistor

Comment: Try disconnecting the motor driver from the arduino and building and running the blink sketch.  If that works, try changing it to blink each pin you had used for the motor driver.

Comment: All arduino pins works fine.

Comment: Could you post a picture of the wiring? Also, just a shot in the dark, try adding a `delay(100)` at the end of the `loop` function.

Comment: I've added delay to loop method and connected led instead of motor. I guess it should be on

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
void setup() {
    pinMode(8, OUTPUT);//MODE
    pinMode(5, OUTPUT);//AENBL
    pinMode(7, OUTPUT);//APHASE
}

void loop() {
  pinMode(7, HIGH);//APHASE
  pinMode(8, HIGH);//MODE
  pinMode(5, HIGH);//AENBL
  delay(200);
  pinMode(5, LOW);//AENBL
}
```

[Here is a description of the breakout board](http://www.pololu.com/product/2135), this shows a requirement of PWM on AENBL for speed control. Try different  delays.

Answer (score 0):

Setting AENBL HIGH should drive the motor at full speed - it has the same effect as analogWrite(5, 255). Dropping it from high to low should stop the motor.

Are you sure the DRV8835 is working properly? You can in theory diagnose it with a logic analyzer, but a scope will work better as the motor outputs aren't really logic. My test setup (yeah, I had one die on me) watched PHASE (just make sure it would toggle), MODE (should be HIGH), and AENBL (should show a square wave for the PWM duty cycle) as logic inputs, then watched the motor outputs on the scope to verify that one of them is the inverse of AENBL and the other is HIGH. Which follows AENBL and which is HIGH depends on PHASE, so you can toggle it if you can only check one output.